# What is the difference between Face Detection and Face Tracking in iOS perspective

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

May be this sounds like a stupid one, but i really curious to know that, what is the difference between "Face Detection and Face Tracking" in iOS perspective? And in what case or which kind of situation should i use the two of them.

Comment: In general Face detection is when a face is in front of camera or a sensor it detects a face and face tracking is movement of face after detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you known about **Vision Framework**!!

Following this link:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision

Vision — a framework to apply high-performance image analysis and computer vision techniques to identify faces, detect features, and classify scenes in images and video.

- Face detection. Detects all faces on selected photo.
- Face landmarks. An image analysis that finds facial features (such as
  the eyes and mouth) in an image.
- Object tracking. Track any object using camera.

Among a lot of new APIs there is the Vision Framework which helps with detection of faces, face features, object tracking and others.

Hope will helpful to you!!

Comment: Thanks for posting your comment. It is really help me a lot. Have a nice day :) @Tubelight

Answer (score 0):

The Face Detection is done by the Apple Framework CoreImage Framework. Available since iOS 5+, (besides the Vision Framework).

You can use the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cidetector

CIDetector to **detect faces.**

Face detection will return face landmarks such as eyes, lips, nose. This frames can be used to modify the faces with image processing.

You can also use the faces found, and use it with a third party Face Recognitions API's to recognize faces (Microsoft face API) .

**Face Tracking** 
Can be used to track the real time location of face features, and possible apply filters to it (snapchat, etc).

Comment: Thanks for posting your comment. But i want only that is that possible to replace feature of human face by any virtual object in 3D.